# Actionbar not visible

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have created an actionbar which has action items and fragment tabs.
However,the actionbar and the fragment tabs are not visible in other activities.
The manifest file also has the required:

```
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
          android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

How can i make the actionbar and fragment tabs permanent for the app?

Comment: You have to call `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` in every Activity you want to display it.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Set up the action bar.
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

I found this piece of code in my project. I hope it helps you out.